# react-router v4 routes with express server (static)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, create-react-app

I created a React app with create-react-app and added react-router v4 to it.

If I run the application with `yarn start` everything is fine.

If I serve the app through an express server (static, no SSR), I cannot navigate to 'complex' route such as http://localhost:3000/xxxxxx/12345.

Here is the route as it it configured with react-router:

```
 <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <LocaleProvider locale={enUS}>
              <Switch>


                <Route path="/xxxxxx/:id" component={MyCOmponent} />
                <Route component={NotFound} />


              </Switch>
            </LocaleProvider>
          </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
      </ApolloProvider>
```

Here is the express server code:

```
// tslint:disable:no-console
// tslint:disable:no-any

import * as express from 'express';
import * as path from 'path';

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var app: express.Application = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function (req: any, res: any) {
  console.log(req.originalUrl);

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`  App is running at http://localhost:${port} in ${app.get('env')} mode`);
  console.log('  Press CTRL-C to stop\n');
});

export default server;
```

I noticed that the javascript bundle requested in the network logs (in chrome) have the wrong url: `xxxxx/static/js/bundle-hash.js` as well as the `req.originalUrl` in the console log.

```
/xxxxx/static/css/main.144af4c5.css
/xxxxx/static/js/main.65b09e30.js
/xxxxx/favicon.ico
```

Why javascript/css files are prefixed by xxxxxx (it should be 
`static/js/bundle-hash.js` not `xxxxx/static/js/bundle-hash.js`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that wasn't related to react-router or express at all. I assume that because express or nginx gave me the error when deployed.

With the create-react-app template, there is a `PUBLIC_URL` env variable that must be set in production.